# What is the correct way to use ngx-bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I have an array of "field" objects I want to render. When the field.type is date I want to render a ngx-bootstrap/datepicker field. My JSON object for the date field looks like this:

```
{
"field": {
  "name": "date_of_occurrence",
  "label": "Date of occurrence",
  "valueType": "date",
  "type": "custom",
  "settings": {
     "required": false
  },
  "organisation": 1,
 },
 "size": 4
}
```

I am trying to render it like this:

```
<form *ngIf="complexForm" name="form" (ngSubmit)="complexForm.valid && send()" [formGroup]="complexForm" novalidate>

<div *ngIf="fieldValue.field.valueType == 'date'" class="form-group">
    <label>{{fieldValue.field.label}}:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input [required]="fieldValue.field.settings.required" type="text" id="complexForm.controls[fieldValue.field.name]" class="form-control date-input" bsDatepicker [(ngModel)]="fieldValue.value">
        <label for="complexForm.controls[fieldValue.field.name]" class="input-group-btn btn btn-primary" (click)="dp.toggle()"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
        <span style="display: inline-block">                
            <datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="fieldValue.value" style="display: block"></datepicker>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

But I get this error:

> ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent
>   formGroup directive.  Try using
>         formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.

I see that the datepicker example uses a "bsValue" to bind to, but I dont want hardcode this as my component simple renders whatever "field" that is in the array and should bind the value back to the value property of that array. Until saved the first time the value property does not exist.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot use `NgModel` inside `[formGroup]`. Instead of `NgModel`, you should operate with `formControlName` which was declared in your form group in component.

Comment: I would suggest to read Angular materials. https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

Comment: @Haseoh Yes, I tried to use that, but could not find the right syntax.  I tried `<input [required]="fieldValue.field.settings.required" type="text" id="complexForm.controls[fieldValue.field.name]" class="form-control date-input" bsDatepicker formControlName="complexForm.controls[fieldValue.field.name]"><datepicker #dp formControlName="complexForm.controls[fieldValue.field.name]" style="display: block"></datepicker>` but that gave me this error: **ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: **

Comment: It cannot find control name, because you didn't initialized such name. When you use form group, you should have some Form Controls like this: `example: new FormControl('')` and then you can use it in your template with `formControlName="example"`. You need to check for your codeand redefine it. Also, check out more about Form Groups on Angular  documentation: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup

Comment: We use the FormBuilder to build the complexForm controls. Basically we do a `this.complexForm = this.formBuilder.group(formInit);` where the formInit is a array with field names; `formInit[fieldValue.field.name] = "";`